# Why is .indexOf is not a function for array object?

Tags: javascript

I've got a list of products and their original prices. I want to put the original prices next to discounted prices. For that, I've created an array with objects. But when I'm trying to see if title matches one of the objects, and if it does, pull the original price- I get ".indexOf is not a function" error.
Here's the code example

```
var items_list = {"Paid Item 1":"900","Paid Item 1 and something else":"600", "Free Item":"65"}; 
var title = "Paid Item 1"; 
if (items_list.indexOf(title)) {
    console.log(items_list[title]);
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: `items_list` is not an array - it is an object. If you want to get a value by its key, simply use: `items_list[title]`

Comment: yeah, that works in python not js

Comment: Even when it works you shouldn't use `indexOf()` as a boolean. It returns `0` if the item is found in the first element of the array, and this is falsey. Use `includes()` or `indexOf() != -1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`items_list` is not an array, but it's an object.
So you can use `in` operator instead of `indexOf` function.

Here is the working version.

```
var items_list = {"Paid Item 1":"900","Paid Item 1 and something else":"600", "Free Item":"65"}; 
var title = "Paid Item 1"; 
if (title in items_list) {
    console.log(items_list[title]);
}
```